# Reference Class Modules by using Class Interface or by using Variant variable?

Tags: excel, vba, class, interface, variant

I’m wondering which of the down below mentioned approaches is the best (and under what circumstances) when referencing Class Modules?
Let me specify what I mean.
(The Code I use below is from https://excelmacromastery.com/)
Here is an example when using Class Interface:

```
Sub Main()

    ' Get the range of data
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Declare the interface variable - this can reference any class
    ' that implements iInterest.
    Dim oInterest As iInterest
    
    ' data variables
    Dim amount As Double, interestType As String
    
    ' Read through the data
    Dim i As Long, result As Double
    For i = 2 To rg.Rows.Count
    
        ' read the current row to variables
        amount = rg.Cells(i, 1).Value
        interestType = rg.Cells(i, 2).Value

        ' Get the interest object
        Set oInterest = ClassFactory(interestType)
        
        ' Calculate the interest
        oInterest.Calculate amount
        
        ' some code
        
        ' Print the interest to the Immediate Window
        oInterest.PrintResult
          
    Next i

End Sub
```

```
Function ClassFactory(ByVal interestType As String) As iInterest

    Dim oInterest As iInterest
            
    If interestType = "A" Then
        Set oInterest = New clsInterestA
    ElseIf interestType = "B" Then
        Set oInterest = New clsInterestB
    ElseIf interestType = "C" Then
        Set oInterest = New clsInterestC
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid type " & interestType
    End If
    
    Set ClassFactory = oInterest

End Function
```

```
' The class for calculating Interest type A
Implements iInterest

Private m_Amount As Double

' Calculate the interest
Sub iInterest_Calculate(ByVal amount As Double)
    m_Amount = amount * 1.1
End Sub

' Print the result to the Immediate Window
Sub iInterest_PrintResult()
    Debug.Print TypeName(Me) & ": " & m_Amount
End Sub
```

```
' The Interface Class named "iInterest" - this is implemented by clsInterestA, clsInterestB and clsInterestC
Sub Calculate(ByVal amount As Double)
End Sub

Sub PrintResult()
End Sub
```

So we have a Standard Module, a Function which creates the appropriate Class Object (“the ClassFactory”) , couple of Class Modules (just including one of the for illustration puropses) and the Class Module Interface.

So the Standard Module’s Sub named “Main” and Function named “ClassFactory” declare the interface variable:

```
Dim oInterest As iInterest
```

This can reference any class that implements the Class Module Interface named “iInterest”.

Here is the other approach which is not using Class Interface:

```
sub Main()
'Rest of the Code same as before

Dim oInterest As Variant 'Previously: Dim oInterest As iInterest

end sub
```

```
Function ClassFactory(ByVal interestType As String) As Variant
'Rest of the Code same as before

Dim oInterest As Variant 'Previously: Dim oInterest As iInterest

end sub
```

Here the same Standard Module’s Sub named “Main” and Function named “ClassFactory” is used but are instead declaring a Variant variable for referencing the same Class Modules (which is not implementing any Class Module Interface anymore).

So my question are as follows:

- **What are the pros and cons of using Class Module Interfaces vs instead using the second technique where a Variant variable instead is used to reference any Class?**
- **When Should I use the “InterFace” approach vs the approach where the Classes are referenced by using a Variant variable?**

I have tried both approaches, but it is still not clear to me.
Maybe this could be the Pros (but I am not an VBA expert so I’m just guessing):

- Less or the exact amount of memory are allocated when declaring the variable for referencing any class as the “InterFace Class” compared to declaring it as Variant.
- The Class Modules which implements the Class Module InterFace, can easily access the “Class InterFace Procedure names” through the Code Window’s dropdown list at the top of the window.

Any support /insights is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. The `Variant` approach is just lazy, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @Rory. But are there not any other benefits of using the "Interface approach"?

Comment: Early binding and type checking are key.

Comment: Of course, that's one huge benefit! Thanks @rory! Early binding to get Intellisence (feature which shows the available methods/procedures and properties of an item when typing code).